# Regex ignore until colon

Tags: regex

Trying to ignore all characters until ":" then select everything until "}"

Having a hard time with it.

**So basically the following:**

```
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-500px:before { content: fa-content($fa-var-500px); }
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-accessible-icon:before { content: fa-content($fa-var-accessible-icon); }
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-accusoft:before { content: fa-content($fa-var-accusoft); }
```

**needs to look like:**

```
-500px
-accessible-icon
-accusoft
```

Have the following working partially here: https://regex101.com/r/QN8gl2/3

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `\.[#]\{[$]fa\-css\-prefix\}-(.*?):.*` ?

Comment: That selects everything.

Comment: Oops, that should be `\.[#]\{[$]fa\-css\-prefix\}(\-.*?):.*` to also include the dash. But if you check the regexp results, it shows Group 1 has what you're trying to match. Otherwise if you don't want to use groups, you're looking for a look-behind and look-ahead combination: `(?<=})-.*?(?=:)` note that JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: Why not just `\}[^:]*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\.#{[$]fa-css-prefix}-(.+?):
```

And you just need to get group 1!

Note that I used a lazy quantifier here since a greedy one will cause a lot of backtracking.

If you are not sure how to get group 1, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression).

Alternatively, you can use the substitution approach,

```
\.#{[$]fa-css-prefix}-(.+?):.+
```

Replace with

```
$1
```

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/QN8gl2/5

Comment: so there is no way to do this without replace with? For instance if I wanted to do this with jquery, how will this work? Where would I insert '$1'?

Comment: @webkitfanz As I said, you can get group 1 if you use the first regex.